# Getting Highcharts tooltip to return an angular directive using templeteUrl?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, highcharts

I have problem similar to
 [Getting Highcharts tooltip to return an angular directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231706/getting-highcharts-tooltip-to-return-an-angular-directive). 
But I tried to create some complex tooltip using directive wich has definied templateUrl instead using inline template. When I use templateUrl, html is loaded asynchronusly and when I'm using it into tooltip formatter it is no loaded yet.

I need use html template because I need to define a tooltpip which should has  clickable navigation button to other site and prepared for one data serie, also should be translated and styled.

Comment: plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/6aV7tzzoWNjlWPtdMxSS?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$compile` with a directive with a `templateUrl`, the content isn't updated until a digest cycle runs.

Since you are within a jQuery event (outside Angular digest cycle) you need to manually trigger a `$scope.$digest()`.

See forked [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i2oOMWtIuoPdYOw3fWc6?p=preview) & snippet below:

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    pointFormatter: function () {
        var element = $compile('<chart-tooltip></chart-tooltip>')($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        return element.html();
    }
}
```

(Also added missing `useHTML: true`)